# I get a black screen when I RENDER the video

Tags: rendering

hey can anyone help me with this, when I start to render the animation with audio I get a black screen with audio . I done everything to make it correct but still its the same. when I first rendered my video it worked without audio since I didn't tick the audio. And when I rendered again after that I get a black screen also even when i render an image I get a black screen for that as well.please help[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it black even from Blender's render view, or is it black when you play the file from your file explorer?

Comment: It is black in both render view and also when I play the file from file explorer.

Comment: I cant attach the file since it is to large...

Comment: How big? Unless you send us raw footages it shouldn't be too much of an issue, eventually try other uploading services like google. But first make sure you check the compress option when using File > save as. Also, don't hesitate to reduce down the amount of files in your video edit, just share the bare minimum for us to encounter the issue. I can't reproduce the issue with Blender 3.0 stable, so it's most likely something wrong on your side or a bug trigger by something specific to your setup. Either way we need your project files x)